# Need to update DateTime in MongoDB using RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to update date in mongodb using Robotframework but getting error "No JSON object could be decoded"

*Below is the code:*

```
${queryJSON}=    Set Variable       
{"pointOfContactEmailAddress":"${emailid}"}    

${updateJSON}=    Set Variable     {"$set": {"status" 
:"EXPIRED","licenseExpiryDate" : new ISODate(${last_7_days}) , 
"activationLinkSentDate" : new ISODate(${last_7_days})}}

${result}=    Retrieve And Update One Mongodb Record    db_name    
collection_name    ${queryJSON}    ${updateJSON}
```

Error:
        ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

any help appreciated.

Comment: It would make your code easier to read if you marked it up as code rather than plain text with bold sections.

Comment: what is `${queryJSON}`? Also, can you please show the actual error? Is it complaining about `${queryJSON}`

Comment: please don't post code in comments. If you're adding more information to your question, please [edit] your question.

Comment: My guess is that it's the `new ISODate(...)` part of the data. I don't think that's JSON, that's javascript. If you hard-code a date in the proper format, does your code work? If so, that would prove that it's the `new ISODate(...)` part that is incorrect.

Comment: Bryan  Oakley is correct - just checked the source of the lib, one of the first operations is `json.loads(queryJSON)` - transforms a string to a python object, in this case a dictionary. And it fails and throws the error because of the `new ISODate()`, which cannot be casted to anything python-ish. Just change them with string representation of the time string, and you should be good.

Comment: yes that's correct hard-code date works. and the problem is with ISODate() part. how can i pass this into the db along with date..?

Comment: `Retrieve And Update One Mongodb Record` is not familiar to me. Is it a custom keyword? If so, posting the code for it might be helpful. If it is not, showing your Resource/Library imports in your code would also be helpful.